# inline-block child auto width strange behavior

Tags: html, css

Consider the following markup and CSS:

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    margin: 7px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: text;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.child {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 1px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.sub-child {
    display: inline-table;
    height: calc(100% - 8px);
    background-color: #ddd;
    line-height: 27px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 0 7px;
    margin: 4px 4px 4px 0;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.sub-child span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.sub-child .img {
    width: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.sub-child .name {
    padding: 0 7px;
    max-width: 100px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.sub-child .closebtn {
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    color: #525353;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sub-child .closebtn:before {
    content: "\00d7";
}

.sub-child .closebtn:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.other-child {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="sub-child">
            <span class="img"></span>
            <span class="name">TestClient</span>
            <span class="closebtn"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-child">
            <span class="img"></span>
            <span class="name">Biggle Boo</span>
            <span class="closebtn"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-child">
            <span class="img"></span>
            <span class="name">Ratty Tatty</span>
            <span class="closebtn"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-child">
            <span class="img"></span>
            <span class="name">Shig Wiggle Miggleson</span>
            <span class="closebtn"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="other-child"></div>
</div>
```

I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a47njuLc/5/) to illustrate the problem I'm having. The `.child` width does not auto expand to the size of it's contents unless the `.img` span is removed. It appears that specifying a fixed width for a table-cell element changes the behavior of the container. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I fixed this by removing the fixed width from the `.img` table-cell element and inserted a sub-element with a fixed width instead. But I'm still unsure why specifying a fixed width for a table-cell should break the `.child` element's auto width.

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 400px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    margin: 7px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: text;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.child {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 1px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.sub-child {
    display: inline-table;
    height: calc(100% - 8px);
    background-color: #ddd;
    line-height: 27px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    padding: 0 7px;
    margin: 4px 4px 4px 0;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.sub-child span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.sub-child .img:before {
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.sub-child .name {
    padding: 0 7px;
    max-width: 100px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.sub-child .closebtn {
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    color: #525353;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sub-child .closebtn:before {
    content: "\00d7";
}

.sub-child .closebtn:hover {
    color: #000;
}

.other-child {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="sub-child">
            <span class="img"></span>
            <span class="name">TestClient</span>
            <span class="closebtn"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-child">
            <span class="img"></span>
            <span class="name">Biggle Boo</span>
            <span class="closebtn"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-child">
            <span class="img"></span>
            <span class="name">Ratty Tatty</span>
            <span class="closebtn"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-child">
            <span class="img"></span>
            <span class="name">Shig Wiggle Miggleson</span>
            <span class="closebtn"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="other-child"></div>
</div>
```

[fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a47njuLc/6/)